# Leaking Reader with tight loop

Tags: go

I have the following code that I think is leaking heavily.  And analysing it I suspect that the `defer r.Close()` is never called.

Would there be a better way of using the Reader and gzip here at all?

```
// Read client data from channel
func (c *Client) listen() {
    timeoutDuration := 30 * time.Second

    reader := bufio.NewReader(c.conn)

    clientBuffer := new(bytes.Buffer)

    for {
        c.conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(timeoutDuration))

        byte, err := reader.ReadByte()

        if err != nil {
            c.conn.Close()
            c.server.onClientConnectionClosed(c, err)
            return
        }

        clientBuffer.WriteByte(byte)
        packet := popPacketFromBuffer(clientBuffer)

        if packet != nil {
            packetBuffer := bytes.NewBuffer(packet)

            r, _ := gzip.NewReader(packetBuffer)
            defer r.Close()

            b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }

            c.server.onNewMessage(c, b)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `defer` functions are only called at the end of the function. Not the loop. So, yes, it is probable that they stay open.

One method would be to encapsulate your tight-loop into a function.

```
func uncompress(packet []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    r, _ := gzip.NewReader(bytes.NewBuffer(packet))
    defer r.Close()
    return ioutil.ReadAll(r)
}

// Read client data from channel
func (c *Client) listen() {
    /* … */

    for {
        /* … */

        if packet != nil {
            b, err := uncompress(packet)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            c.server.onNewMessage(c, b)
        }

    }
}
```

Another would be to unroll the defer call and do it manually.

```
// Read client data from channel
func (c *Client) listen() {
    /* … */

    for {
        /* … */

        if packet != nil {
            r, _ := gzip.NewReader(bytes.NewBuffer(packet))
            b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            r.Close()
            c.server.onNewMessage(c, b)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I suspected it wouldn't so that is great. Would it be possible to Init the reader outside the for loop?

Comment: Well, you could probably use the `gzip.Reader` directly on your connection reader. It makes sense since I imagine that your connection is yielding gziped data, but I never used these packages, so I can't guarantee that…

Comment: @LeeArmstrong: If you want to reuse the gzip.Reader, it has a Reset method specifically so you don't have to allocate a new one every loop..

Comment: @JimB Ah thanks, trouble I have though (I think) is that I feed it the packet buffer and that isn't there until later on?

Comment: @LeeArmstrong: I'm not sure what you mean. You have the `[]byte` (the "packet") at that point, and you're reading it all immediately. If each "packet" is an individual gzip stream, then `gzipReader.Reset(bytes.NewBuffer(packet))` would do the same with less allocation. This looks a little strange though, since you usually compress things at a lower level for greater efficiency.

Comment: Thanks, and yes I do want to keep allocations down.  I tried https://gist.github.com/leearmstrong/deb6b309f75827298da15a6322a31d66 but I get a crash sadly.  That is essentially what I think I want to achieve